# How to use SQL IN operator into lambda expression for Guid type?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, lambda

How can I do this SQL statement and convert it into lambda?

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Notification]
where RelatedId in ('A665F990-8683-40E4-B303-F2C800B01172', 'BFFCAD51-6D99-427F-9971-5DA3116279C0')
```

I just tried it out but there is no `.Contains()` function when the property is in Guid.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` should work:

```
var notifications = new Guid[]{ ... };
var query = db.Notification
    .Where(n => notifications.Contains(n.RelatedId));
```